# Kendo template add space where code is

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

So I am using this bit of code to create a template for a kendo dropdown list

```
 <script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">      
    #if(Text.indexOf('(Deleted)') > -1){#
    <span style="display:none"></span>
    #}else{#
    <span>#:Text#</span>
    #}#    
</script>
```

The problem here is that the line of code is being interpreted into white space. What I mean is that white space is being added. 
When I bind a function to the select event and try to get the text of the selected item

```
function typeChanged(e) {
   console.log(e.item.text());
}
$("#...").data("kendoDropDownList").bind("select", typeChanged);
```

What console.log return is the text with 2 empty lines above and 2 below. Please refer to picture. So what I want to know is there a way to strip those empty line beside calling the trim function?
[image]

**Additional Info**
When I added more line of code in the the template it also added an extra line

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #if(Text.indexOf('(Deleted)') > -1){}#  <-- Added this      
    #if(Text.indexOf('(Deleted)') > -1){#
    <span style="display:none"></span>
    #}else{#
    <span>#:Text#</span>
    #}#
</script>
```

[image]

When I completely remove the use of the template

Old:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
              .BindTo(list)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .HtmlAttributes(attributes)
              ...
              .TemplateId("itemTemplate")
              .ValueTemplateId("tagTemplate")
        )
```

New:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
              .BindTo(list)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .HtmlAttributes(attributes)
              ...
              < deleted >
              .ValueTemplateId("tagTemplate")
        )
```

Console.log() returns fine.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the your datasource declaration and how/where you are using the template in your code?

Comment: @whipdancer please see the additional info. I have added more information. I doubt it is the datasource

Comment: It is rather odd. Does the dropdown list itself render correctly? What is the output if you `console.log(e.item)`?

Comment: @whipdancer It renders correctly. `console.log(e.item)` returns an object. `[object Object]{0: HTMLLIElement {...}, context: HTMLLIElement {...}, jquery: "1.11.3", length: 1, selector: ""}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that Kendo was actually reading the line break once I add it all to one line it worked

```
<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">#if(Text.indexOf('(Deleted)') > -1){#<span style="display:none"></span>#}else{#<span>#:Text#</span>#}# </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the empty span tags? If not, you can reverse the logic in your template so that the empty spaces are never created.

```
#if(Text.indexOf('(Deleted)') == -1){#
    <span>#:Text#</span>
#}#
```

Comment: The empty space are caused by the line of code. So in your example `#if(Text.indexOf('(Deleted)') == -1){#` will cause an empty line.

Comment: If `indexOf` returns -1, it means that `(Deleted)` was not found. Based on the logic, I'm assuming that if `(Deleted)` is not found you want to render a span with the value from `:TEXT`.

Comment: Yes. The logic works fine. It how kendo is interpreting those line of code. I will elaborate more in my original question.